# IE7 regex issue - Regex that work in every browser does not work in ie7

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, internet-explorer-7, passwords

I have a regex validating a password value to be > 6 < 25 characters with at least one number.

```
var passwordRegEx = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,25}$/;
if(!#quickRegister_Password').val().test(pass))
{
   errorMgs += 'Your password must be at least 6 characters and have at least 1 number and 1 letter.\r\n';
}
```

It works in Firefox, Chrome, IE8 (IE7 ran from compatability in IE8) but not IE7 standalone.

Comment: Format your code by intending with 4 spaces or using the code button. Also, what is up with the `!#`?

Comment: Really!?  There's a bug in IE7!? I am shocked, *shocked*!

Answer (score 4):

I think you have run into the regular expression lookahead bug in IE7's javascript engine.

Run the tests on this page and see if your results match up; you will probably see the lookahead tests fail: http://www.javascriptjedi.com/regex/tests/

Information:

- http://development.thatoneplace.net/2008/05/bug-discovered-in-internet-explorer-7.html
- http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug
- http://forums.asp.net/p/1405215/3056174.aspx