# Regex match a strong password with two or more special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I need to regex match a password field using javascript with the following requirements:

- At least 15 characters
- two or more lower case letters
- two or more upper case letters
- two or more digits
- two or more of the following special characters: !@#$%^&*-

I have a regex that takes care of MOST cases:

```
/^.*(?=.{15,})(?=.{2,}\d)(?=.{2,}[a-z])(?=.{2,}[A-Z])(?=.{2,}[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\-]).*$/
```

The problem here is with the symbols, it works with:

> ```
> P@ssw0rdP@ssw0rd
> Pssw0rdPssw0rd@@
> Pssw0rd@@Pssw0rd
> ```

But not:

> ```
> @@Pssw0rdPssw0rd
> ```

I have a random password generator set up to exhaustively test this, so any ideas are greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I think this cannot be done with *one* regex.

Comment: @Salman: why not? Ever heard of lookaheads?

Comment: I recommend against doing this. Enforced password security is one of the main reasons of users creating "password1", or "PAssword!@12345" in your case.

Comment: I bet "This is my password and you won't brute force it any time soon. It is easy to remember, but hard to crack." is stronger than "PAssword!@12345" and it does not meet these requirements.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: nope. will research :)

Comment: There are some additional features I left out of here that doesn't affect the regex. There are additional checks at the DB level to make sure the password does not contain dictionary values, your username, any numbers related to your information, etc.

Comment: @yorick I think with users that lazy if you *don't* enforce password security they'll probably pick something like `p` (I have seen this)

Comment: I prefer to break the various conditions into steps in code rather than through one complex regex. That way you can report to the user *why* their password has failed security validation. Also easier to verify that it actually works.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
/^(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2})(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){2})(?=(?:.*\d){2})(?=(?:.*[!@#$%^&*-]){2}).{15,}$/
```

---

Your lookaheads are wrong. The pattern

```
(?=.{2,}[class])
```

means to match 2 or more characters (no matter what characters), then followed by 1 character of the desired class. This is entirely different from "2 or more character of the desired class" you specified.

To correctly test if a character of desired class is in the text, use

```
(?=.*[class])
```

and since you want to check it twice, repeat the pattern

```
(?=.*[class].*[class])
# equivalent to (?=(?:.*[class]){2})
```

Comment: Tested and confirmed with 100,000 randomly created passwords.  You sir are a regex jedi, thanks!

Comment: Would like to add that this regex works multi-platform, but if you use it in javascript it will NOT work in IE7 because of the lookahead issue in the javascript engine. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999733/ie7-regex-issue-regex-that-work-in-every-browser-does-not-work-in-ie7)

Comment: Why won't they let you delete comments??

Comment: This answer is criminally low-voted. Indeed "You sir are a regex jedi, thanks!" @kennytm

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure a single regexp is the way to go for this test.

Personally i'd implement it something like this: (treat as pseudo code, i haven't tested it)

```
function testPassword(pw) {
    var len = pw.length;
    if(len < 15) return false;
    if(pw.replace(/[a-z]/,'').length > len - 2) return false;
    if(pw.replace(/[A-Z]/,'').length > len - 2) return false;
    if(pw.replace(/[0-9]/,'').length > len - 2) return false;
    if(pw.replace(/[!@#$%^&*-]/,'').length > len - 2) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I like your thinking, but I need regex because it works across multiple languages, so easier code reuse was key for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good explanations already, so I'm just piling on ...

`/^`
`(?= .{15} )`
`(?= (?:.*[[:lower:]]){2} )`
`(?= (?:.*[[:upper:]]){2} )`
`(?= (?:.*[[:digit:]]){2} )`
`(?= (?:.*[!@#$%^&*-]){2} )`
`/x`