# REGEX password validation without special characters

Tags: regex

I am using this regex to validate my password.
My password -

- should be alphanumeric ONLY,
- contains at least 8 characters,
- at least 2 numbers
- and at least 2 alphabet.

My regex is

```
^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])(?!.*\W).*$
```

but unfortunately it still matches if I try to put special characters at the beginning.
For example `@password12`, `!password12`.

Comment: No idea, but why on earth would you want to prevent special characters in passwords? If you care about strong passwords (which apparently you do, concerting the rules you set), just allow people to type whatever they want. Why not let them type unicode characters even?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670639/regex-match-a-strong-password-with-two-or-more-special-characters

Comment: In which language? Regular expressions are rarely the only tool to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: you might want to limit valid characters, so that if you plan for the user to access from device with limited character input (smartphone etc...), they will be able to reproduce their password.

Comment: @Billy: No you don't. You only want to limit like that if *you are the user (of a not-so-smartphone)*. You don't want to limit like that if you are the provider.

Answer (score 2):

Because your pattern begins and ends with `.*`, it will match anything at the beginning or end of the string, including special characters.

You shouldn't be solving this problem with a single regular expression, it makes the code hard to read and hard to modify. Write one function for each rule using whatever makes sense for that rule, then your validation script becomes crystal clear:

```
if is_alpha_only(password) && 
   len(password) > = 8 && 
   has_2_or_more_numbers(password) &&
   has_2_or_more_alpha(password) ...
```

Seriously, what's the point of cramming all of that into a single regular expression?

And why disallow special characters? There's simply no reason for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex in case insensitive mode:

```
^(?=[a-z]*[0-9][a-z]*[0-9])^(?=[0-9]*[a-z][0-9]*[a-z])[a-z0-9]{8,}$
```

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/JmEwEBGcmr)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation in which the client needed 4 alpha, 1 number, and between 8 and 20 characters.  I've adapted my solution to your problem:

```
^(?=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]){2})(?=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*\d){2})[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$
```

I understand the other answers dissuading you from this route, but sometimes the client wants what the client wants, regardless of your arguments to the contrary.