# Regular Expression Help for Internet Explorer 7

Tags: asp.net, regex

Regular Expressions aren't my strong point but I had been using the below to validate Passwords were between 8 and 20 characters and had at least one digit and one upper and lower case character.

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,20})
```

All was working fine until I tested in Internet Explorer which was returning all passwords as invalid.

This is due to the Internet Explorer 7 bug described here [IE7 regex issue - Regex that work in every browser does not work in ie7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999733/ie7-regex-issue-regex-that-work-in-every-browser-does-not-work-in-ie7)

Following the blog posts on the above questions I see some people say that in most cases the regular expression can be reworked so that it works on IE7 but as I say my regular expression knowledge isn't the best so if anyone new how to make the above work on IE7 that would be great.

I am using ASP.NET so another option is to set EnableClientScript to False so that the regular expression is checked server side but I'd rather have it checked client side first if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at the link you posted. And [here you go](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug):

```
/((?=.{8,20})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*)/
```

Also, following the same link, this should work as well:

```
/((?=.+\d)(?=.+[A-Z])(?=.+[a-z]).{8,20})/
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't seem to get the above to work on any browser as it always comes back as false. I also tried them on http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @MikeM you're right, he probably didn't. Also, thanks for the comment, I just copy & pasted his regex when they're missing too :)

Comment: Thanks ((?=.{8,20})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*) worked perfectly in IE7